# highcharts stacked area with irregular x-intervals

Tags: highcharts, axis, intervals, area, stacked

After a couple of weeks working with Highcharts, we are facing problems to generate charts that fit to out data structure. Would be nice if somebody can give us a hint.

Here is the problem:

- We want to create a stacked area chart for 2 or more series.
- Since our x-values have irregular intervals we tried to set up value pairs for each data point [x,y]

However, the area chart does not stack our y-values. Any suggestions?

Here is an example of our problem: [link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FX7XE/1/)

Thanks for your help!

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Irregular point intervalls stacked area'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'value'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                stacked: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'test 1',
            data: [[0, 7.0], [1, 6.9], [1.5, 9.5], [3, 14.5]]
        }, {
            name: 'test 2',
            data: [[0, 3.9],[1, 4.2], [1.5, 5.7], [3, 8.5]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use stacking not stacked in plotOptions-> area

```
stacking: 'normal',
```

updated you fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FX7XE/2/

hope this will be useful for you

Comment: #blush...what a mistake. Thanks for your help!